# Batch File Conditional execution logging

Tags: windows, rest, batch-file, curl

I am using curl to upload bulk files to a remote server using REST in Windows with a batch script. I need to track successful and unsuccessful events. For unsuccessful events, I'd like to capture the JSON response from the remote server.

If I add an append to the command ">>debug.log" I am able to capture all of the events; however I am dealing with about 50k or more files, so I'd only like to capture the failures. I tried just writing to the file once ">debug.log" and then parse out the information before the next loop, but the file always remains empty if I am not appending.

I would appreciate any advice.

```
for %%f in (*) do ( 

    curl !url! --request POST --header "Accept:application/json" --header "Authorization:%auth%" -F "uploadFile=@%filepath%\%%f" >> %mypath%\%logfolder%\debuglog.txt && (
        echo %filepath%\%%f success >> %mypath%\%logfolder%\successlog.txt
    ) || (
        echo %filepath%\%%f error >> %mypath%\%logfolder%\errorlog.txt

        REM set JSONDEBUG=
        REM for /F "delims=" %%w in (%mypath%\%logfolder%\debuglog.txt) do ( set JSONDEBUG=!JSONDEBUG! %%w )

        REM set JSONDEBUGPARSE=!JSONDEBUG:~11,-1!
        REM echo !JSONDEBUGPARSE! >> %mypath%\%logfolder%\errorlog.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you post an example of debuglog.txt and what you want errorlog.txt to look like?

Answer (score 1):

You could write the curl output to a temporary file, without append, and then in your failure branch you can type the temp file and append it to your log. I added some line continuation just to make things easier to read.

```
for %%f in (*) do ( 
  curl !url! --request POST ^
             --header "Accept:application/json" ^
             --header "Authorization:%auth%" ^
             -F "uploadFile=@%filepath%\%%f" > curltemp.txt && (
    echo %filepath%\%%f success >> %mypath%\%logfolder%\successlog.txt
  ) || (
    echo %filepath%\%%f error >> %mypath%\%logfolder%\errorlog.txt
    type curlTemp.txt >> %mypath%\%logfolder%\debuglog.txt 
    REM set JSONDEBUG=
    REM for /F "delims=" %%w in (%mypath%\%logfolder%\debuglog.txt) do ( set JSONDEBUG=!JSONDEBUG! %%w )
    REM set JSONDEBUGPARSE=!JSONDEBUG:~11,-1!
    REM echo !JSONDEBUGPARSE! >> %mypath%\%logfolder%\errorlog.txt
  )
)
del curlTemp.txt
```